# CSS - How to expand size of hero background div/image as content expands vertically

Tags: css

I've looked at a few other answers on here, but I haven't been able to fix the following issue in my use case. [I have a codepen here](https://codepen.io/tanner-brandt/pen/VwvwqrE)

I have a user hero background wrapper that has the property `background-size:cover`. This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Everything looks good, but if the user were to put in a much longer description of themselves, then the text would spill out of the div:

[image]

So what css properties should I change in order to preserve the margin of the user hero div and background image to the content? [Here is a link to my code pen](https://codepen.io/tanner-brandt/pen/VwvwqrE)

Comment: You're using `position: absolute` in many of your elements, which causes them to be taken out of the layout flow and therefore the parent elements do not grow in size with the content. Is there a reason why everything is absolutely positioned when you can rely on flexbox and etc. to do autolayout for you?

Comment: Oh no, there is no reason that those had to be set to an absolute fixed position. I was confused on how to keep the background image in the background wrapper at the perfect height, and my code spiraled downhill. Implementing flexbox as you mentioned is ideal, and @user13160957 answer fixes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `position: absolute;` to position your elements, which takes them out of the regular document flow. Absolutely positioned child elements don't stretch their parents, nor is their behavior affected by the siblings.

So basically, you would want to move the div with the class `user-hero-photo-layout-container` above the div with the class `userheroinfowrapper-5wLB0y-layout-container` in your HTML markup.

And then remove the `position: absolute;` from both of them.

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/g3L2qapz/1/) an example of how your code might look like after these changes.